# Azure Web App PaaS (App Service Plan) with Azure SQL connection inside vNet performance vs outside vNet

Tags: performance, azure, azure-sql-database, latency, vnet

I have the following setup:

```
|--------------------- Internet -------------------------|
  WebApp    <---- non-vNet traffic ---->   Azure SQL Db
```

- `WebApp` and `Azure SQL Db` are in the same data centre.
- There is currently no vNet.
- There's a lot of unavoidable "chatter" going back and forth between `Azure SQL Db` and `WebApp`
- The connection string in `WebApp` is a DNS name for `Azure SQL Db` (e.g. `mydatabase.database.windows.net`), so it's resolving to an external IP.
- I'm trying to squeeze as much performance out of my app as possible by reducing any network overhead incurred with the "chatter".
- I can't seem to find any docs specifically talking about network performance inside vs outside a vNet on Azure.

#### 1. Is it possible to place a Web App and an Azure SQL Db inside a vNet and if so what caveats are there to this?

#### 2. Will I get better network performance by doing this?

```
|----------------------- vNet -----------------------------|
  WebApp     <---- vNet traffic ---->     Azure SQL Server
```

Answer (score 1):

If anything you'll probably get worse latency given the Web App has to do SSTP (point-to-site VPN) to reach that VNET.  You'll need to bench both setups but i wouldn't bother.

What i would bother with is adding a caching layer if you don't already have one, in-process or distributed (Redis). Now, that's going to be a dramatic change of events for your fetch latency.

Comment: Thanks, when you say "I wouldn't bother", what's that based on? Experience? Documents you've read? Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Also, even with a distributed Redis caching layer, there will be a network latency so I suppose my question still stands: is there any network performance improvement between *any* services inside a vNet vs outside a vNet?

Comment: It's a fair question but you're assuming someone else has already benched this which i find a little far-fetched. Go and bench it.

Comment: With due respect, the whole point of asking questions on this platform is to establish if someone else has already come across this problem and can help me and others by sharing their findings.

Answer (score -1):

We can definitely deploy the web app inside a VNET using the azure app service environment instead of hosting it in a app service plan.

This is appropriate for application workloads that require:

1. Very high scale.
2. Isolation and secure network access.
3. High memory utilization.

More info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/

Comment: 4. very high cost

Comment: Also this doesn't answer my questions as to whether a vNet is possible between WebApps and Azure SQL and if it will improve network performance